# If then statement crashes, csh

Tags: if-statement, csh

I am trying to write a script using csh to check our archives for data, and if the data isn't there to enter it. I wrote an if then statement to check for the data file. It looks like this:

```
if (! -e $site*d.Z) then
    cdraw2rnx
    set site = `echo $site | tr "[a-z]" "[A-Z]"` 
    if (! -e $site*T00*) then
        echo "No data for" $site "exists in Archive"
    else 
        echo "Data Found"

    endif
else 
    echo $site "is Rinexed" 
endif
```

cdraw2rnx is another script.

when I run the script it gets to this if statement and then returns

```
site*d.Z: no match
```

and then it stops. My understanding was that since there is no match for the site it should then execute the then portion of statement, but it just ends. I am new to scripting, and don't really know what I'm doing. So any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've added a csh tag, since this at least looks like a csh script. If that's incorrect, please update with the correct tag to indicate what language you're using.

Comment: thanks Kieth it is in csh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In csh, a matching failure is a fatal error; it doesn't just cause the condition to be false.

Assuming `$site` is "FOO", then this:

```
if (! -e $site*d.Z) then
```

will expand to a list of all files whose names start with `FOO` and end with `d.Z`. If you have more than one such file, you'll have a syntax error, since `-e` takes only one argument. If you don't have any, your script will crash, as you've seen.

You can't use wildcards to test for files that may or may not exist.

Instead, you can use `grep` with a regular expression (which, it should be noted, as somewhat different syntax and semantics than wildcards). For example (I haven't tested this):

```
set count = `ls | grep -c "^${site}.*d`.Z$"
if ($count == 1) then
    ....
endif
```

`grep -c` prints the number of lines that match the regular expression. I used double quotes on the regexp so that the variable `${site}` will be expanded. I added curly braces to be sure that the end of the name `site` is recognized (not necessary in this case, but good practice). The `^` and `$` ensure that the regular expression matches the entire file name.

The rest of the script is left as an exercise.

And of course I can't discuss csh scripting without posting [this link](http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/versus/csh.whynot).

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for taking the time to explain this to me and for the csh scripting link. It was a great help. I would upvote your answer, but I have no reputation here.

Comment: @javery1289: You have a little more now.